# ImportError: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi3, importerror

I am trying to run an Arducam MT9J001 camera on a raspberry pi 3b+. I am getting the following error when I try to run the program, "ImportError: libcblas.so3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory." I have the computer vision software downloaded onto the raspberry pi, though it seems that it is still not working. I'm not sure what other information is viable to this project, but if there is something else I should be specifying please let me know.

Comment: Hello, you should try: sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get install libcblas-dev. It worked for me in the same situation.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Do I need to restart my Pi after running these installs? Unfortunately I am getting the same error even after your advised installation code.

Comment: Is it the same error? Or are you missing a different package?

Comment: oh it is now "ImportError: libatlas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: What worked for me (I was missing some dependencies):

pip3 install opencv-python

sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev

sudo apt-get install libqtgui4

sudo apt-get install libqt4-test

Comment: That worked great!! Thank you! I am now getting the error "ImportError: /home/pi/ArduCAM_USB_Camera_Shield/RaspberryPi/Python/Streaming_demo/ArducamSDK.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct" Is this now an unrelated error to this thread?

Comment: Yes, I think you should start a new question about this one. I'm glad it helped you at least so far.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

What worked for me (I was missing some dependencies):

```
pip3 install opencv-python 
sudo apt-get install libcblas-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev 
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 
sudo apt-get install libqt4-test
```

Comment: In addition, I also neede to install 
`libilmbase-dev`
`libopenexr-dev`
`libgstreamer1.0-dev` 
`libavcodec-dev`
`libavformat-dev`
`libswscale-dev`
and  `libwebp-dev`

Comment: Thank  you! This has been a big help

Comment: libatlas-base-dev is now replaced by libatlas-base-dev so you might want to update the update to this: sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libatlas-base-dev libjasper-dev libqtgui4 
libqt4-test

Comment: @blackjack75 thanks, this definitly helped out a lot since my raspberrypi 3b couldn't find the package lbcblas-dev!

Answer (score 80):

You need to install only one package with neccessary shared object for it to work

```sh
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

Comment: on raspberry 4 Raspbian I get ``ImportError: libjasper.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory``

Comment: @hamaney You'll need to install that library `sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev`

Comment: awesome. worked for pi 3b+ ! (issue occured when installing pandas, no real need for libqtgui4)

Answer (score 29):

Exact same solution as @thvs86 but here's a single 1 line copy-paste so you don't have to insert each command individually:

`pip3 install opencv-contrib-python; sudo apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev libhdf5-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libatlas-base-dev libjasper-dev  libqtgui4  libqt4-test`

Comment: all at once didn't work for me. @thvs86 one-by-one approach did work. Don't know why, but if this doesn't work, give the other solution a try!