# object detection error: ImportError: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm  trying to activated EdjeElectronics object detection project
on my raspberry pi 4b and when i try to start the object detection it gives me this error:
ImportError: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.

Can you please give me suggestions on how to solve this error.

EdjeElectronics object detection project: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-on-the-Raspberry-Pi.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: libcblas should be part of libatlas3, did you install this dependency? Check that /usr/lib/libcblas.so.3 exists

Comment: /usr/lib/libcblas.so.3 does not exist for me but i did sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

Comment: is there any libcblas.so.3 file existing on your system? try `sudo find / -iname libcblas.so.3`

Comment: when i run sudo find / -iname libcblas.so.3 it gives me:  find: '/lib/moudels/4.19.118-v7+/kernel/gpu/drm': structure needs cleaning and find: '/run/user/1000/gvfs': premission denied

Comment: in that case, it would perhaps be more helpful to find out what libatlas-base-dev actually came with. can you run `dpkg-query -L libatlas-base-dev | grep cblas` . do you see it there?

Comment: when i run the command it gives me: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cblas-atlas.h,  /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcblas.a  and /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcblas.so

Comment: in that case, the simplest thing to do might be to add a symlink `libcblas.so.3` to the `libcblas.so` given in the output

Comment: how can i add the symlink libcblas.so.3 to the libcblas.so given in the output ?

Comment: out of interest, is it for sure libatlas3 that you installed? which version does `dpkg -l | grep libatlas-base-dev` produce?

Comment: the symlink can be made with `ln -s`, just be sure to put the link somewhere in your library path

Comment: when i run dpkg -l | grep libatlas-base-dev it produces the verasion 3.10.3

Comment: ok then, do the symlink thing `ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcblas.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcblas.so.3` or look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347759/importerror-libcblas-so-3-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dire?rq=1 , maybe it works for you too.

Comment: when i run the command it gave me ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcblas.so.3': file exists and i've already read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347759/importerror-libcblas-so-3-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dire?rq=1

Comment: ok then, if it exists, then it could be that /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf is not part of your load path?

Comment: then how can i check if its apart of my load path?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setting-changing-library-path/

Comment: can you also include the complete stacktrace in the question?