# RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9 from import cv2

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, opencv

Numpy version- 1.9.2
opencv - 2.14.13
python - 2.7.5
Windows 8.1

These are the updated versions installed but still the error continues.

```
 >>> import cv2
     RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xa but this version of numpy is 0x9

     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
     import cv2
```

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import)

Comment: The basic error is that the installed version of numpy is older than that required by opencv.

Comment: What is the correct version?

Comment: The correct version will be the current version for your setup. That is not to be difficult, but you should ___really___ read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import first.