# I am getting the following import error, although I have numpy installed

Tags: python-3.x, windows, numpy, tensorflow, tensorlayer

When I tried to run dataloader.py I got the following import error.
I tried the code line by line and I found this error came while importing tensorlayer as t1.

```
$C:\Users\chinm\Desktop\Malta\Project\image synthesis\text-to-image-master>py data_loader.py
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
>   ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "<frozen
>   importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load SystemError:
>   <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with
>   an error set ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to
>   import ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import 2019-03-25
>   16:12:44.506244: F tensorflow/python/lib/core/bfloat16.cc:675] Check
>   failed: PyBfloat16_Type.tp_base != nullptr

```
import os
import re
import time
import nltk
import re
import string
import tensorlayer as tl
from utils import *
```

Comment: You should search the old questions before writing a new question. Your question is duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge numpy
```