# Anaconda/Python site-packages subfolders with tilde in name - what are they?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, python-packaging

Today, I went to change the config of matplotlib. Searching `matplotlibrc` revealed I have two of them:

[image: Screenshot of search results, with two entries: <code>C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~-tplotlib\mpl-data</code> and <code>C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data</code>]

Looking at the `site-packages` folder, I found a lot of packages have a tilde in their name:

[image: Windows Explorer screenshot showing that site-packages contains many other folders starting with a <code>~</code> symbol, like <code>~klearn</code> and <code>~yximport</code>]

- `~klearn` is `sklearn` , but there is another `sklearn` .
- `~atplotlib` is matplotlib too, changed date is `2018-11`
- `~-tplotlib`'s changed date is `2019-3.15`
- `matplotlib`'s changed date is `2019-3.28` (I did update matplotlib recently)

What are these tilde name packages used for? Can I delete them safely?

Comment: In Windows convention a directory/file starting with ~ is mostly backup. Not sure if that's also the case with anaconda. You can try cut-pasting the directories to another one and see if everything works fine.

Comment: @Taegyung Alteady tested, fine after delete . But it shouldn't keep the old package like this .  I afraid they have some other usage .

Comment: You can check with `conda clean --all --dry-run`

Comment: would there be a way todo a `pip clean` too?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is it possible that you installed those particular packages with pip? If so, then the mangled directories are probably the temporary directories that pip creates when it uninstalls a package (or when it uninstalls a package in preparation for updating a package).

I dug through the pip source code and found [this snippet](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/19.2.2/src/pip/_internal/utils/temp_dir.py#L87-L106) which is evidently only used on uninstalling packages:

```py
class AdjacentTempDirectory(TempDirectory):
    """Helper class that creates a temporary directory adjacent to a real one.
    Attributes:
        original
            The original directory to create a temp directory for.
        path
            After calling create() or entering, contains the full
            path to the temporary directory.
        delete
            Whether the directory should be deleted when exiting
            (when used as a contextmanager)
    """
    # The characters that may be used to name the temp directory
    # We always prepend a ~ and then rotate through these until
    # a usable name is found.
    # pkg_resources raises a different error for .dist-info folder
    # with leading '-' and invalid metadata
    LEADING_CHARS = "-~.=%0123456789"

    ...
```

If that's what these files are, then you can safely delete them.