# numpy version problem while intall Opencv in ArcGIS 10.4 default python

Tags: numpy, opencv, arcgis

I want to use Hyperlink in ArcGIS 10.4 to open my script which will show openCV window.

As ArcGIS 10.4 I'm using comes with Python 2.7.10 and Numerical Python 1.9.2

and OpenCV requires numpy and will update it while installing

So I tried pip install opencv-python and it succeed

but when I want to use the codes, it shows

'''
ImportError: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\site-packages\numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version.
'''

I tried to pip uninstall and reinstall numpy and opencv each multiple times
but none of them helped

I end up delete the whole Python27 folder and run repair ArcGIS to get the numpy run normally.

I wonder if I use pip install --user opencv-python if it will show again multi-version of numpy

I'm not the admin account but I did all the upper moves in CMD opened as administrator

but I wonder how to run OpenCV and ArcGIS funcitonally from hyperlink, by input two field values.

```
import my_function

def OpenLink ( [OBJECTID] , [Path]  ):
bagfile_path = [Path] 
Object_id = [OBJECTID] 
my_function.measurement(bagfile_path,Object_id)
return
```

Comment: Try using answers from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import)

Comment: thank you, I used pip install --user and it works, though I cant update the matplotlib without breaking ARCGIS