# ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import & can't read cv.imread()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I am trying to run this code:

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread("1.jpg")
cv2.imshow("image",img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem I keep getting is this error report:

```
 from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

& i'am also installed opencv-python for cv2 cv2 is working. but i can't use cv2.imread()

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because your'e using bad version of `numpy`.
[You can fix it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import):

```
python3 -m pip install numpy -I
```

Please check the compatible version for your platform and reinstall it specifying the version number in above command.

Comment: yes i am also tried reinstall process but i got same result again...