# DAT file in python

Tags: python, encoding

I have a problem with .dat files in Python: I can not encode it. I have tried UTF-8, ASCII and many more.

```
import re

with open("mixture1.dat",'r', encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    text = "".join(lines)

print(text)
```

Here is [the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/myvuvbzz41qvvww/mixture1.dat?dl=0) for the "mixture1.dat". There should be something related in chemistry but I could not open it for a week. How should I do it?

EDIT: SOLUTION

```
import pickle

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename,  'rb')  as  FID:
        mp  = pickle.Unpickler(FID)
        data = mp.load()
    return data
```

Worked fine

Comment: Opening a binary file like that has no chance of success.  strings says "numpy.core.multiarray".  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import

Comment: What should i do then? I should open it and it corresponds to a mixture of two molecules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy`](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) for this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.fromfile('mixture1.dat', dtype=float)

print(data.size)
print(data[:20])
```

Output:

```
23767
[ 5.43235748e-312  7.01653493e-205  3.63521590e+228  9.77081644e+199
  4.03065734e-277 -2.37251204e-214  9.10016855e+276  4.27255706e+180
 -2.89898361e-211 -8.83065826e-211  3.49131717e+070  1.91561942e+053
 -3.80240360e-210  2.67555322e-318 -8.83065517e-211 -5.81601764e+181
 -5.71181552e-277  8.93904783e+014  3.37067979e-234  3.07882662e-292]
```

Comment: What is the meaning of these numbers? Is it a header or the numbers in the file itself? Cause it was given that data is given in a binary file with 10001 values corresponding
to the normalized fluorescence signal measured for 1 µs with a time step of 100 ps.

Comment: My understanding from the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) is that the numbers are the data in the file itself.

Comment: I have multiple that kind of file. Numbers in the even indexes are the same
[ 1.10687736e+193 -3.04853105e+012 -8.83065517e-211  7.82932173e+185
 -5.71172958e-277  8.93904783e+014 -1.21750579e+288  3.07882662e-292
  3.90254972e+267  6.53306071e+089]

[ 1.10687736e+193 -7.26428739e+192 -8.83065517e-211  3.21748662e+272
 -5.71171472e-277  8.93904783e+014 -2.18020972e+271  3.07882662e-292
 -1.42643138e-238  6.53306071e+089]

Comment: @SamadzadeMuhammed you should ask the meaning of the numbers to the people who created your .dat files. We can only help you decode the file, but we cannot tell you its meaning.