# Tensorflow Object Detection API - ImportError when I try to run model_builder_test.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, intel-oneapi

I am creating a custom object detection model using Tensor Object detection API. I installed everything as mentioned in [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/luxonis/depthai-ml-training/blob/master/colab-notebooks/Easy_Object_Detection_With_Custom_Data_Demo_Training.ipynb#scrollTo=CjDHjhKQofT5) notebook and following the same steps as mentioned in this notebook but when I try to run model_builder_test.py file

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/../models/research/:/../models/research/slim/'
!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/home/u83829/object_detection_usecase/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 23, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import image_resizer_builder
  File "/home/u83829/object_detection_usecase/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/builders/image_resizer_builder.py", line 19, in <module>
    from object_detection.core import preprocessor
  File "/home/u83829/object_detection_usecase/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py", line 82, in <module>
    from object_detection.core import densepose_ops
  File "/home/u83829/object_detection_usecase/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/core/densepose_ops.py", line 29, in <module>
    import scipy.io
  File "/glob/development-tools/versions/oneapi/2021.3/inteloneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/io/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from .matlab import loadmat, savemat, whosmat, byteordercodes
  File "/glob/development-tools/versions/oneapi/2021.3/inteloneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .mio import loadmat, savemat, whosmat
  File "/glob/development-tools/versions/oneapi/2021.3/inteloneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .mio4 import MatFile4Reader, MatFile4Writer
  File "/glob/development-tools/versions/oneapi/2021.3/inteloneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio4.py", line 9, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
  File "/glob/development-tools/versions/oneapi/2021.3/inteloneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 228, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "/glob/development-tools/versions/oneapi/2021.3/inteloneapi/intelpython/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import (csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks,
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I'm using python 3.7.10 and tensorflow 2.6.0 on Intel OneAPI Devcloud. Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: You may need to modify your `numpy` version. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import ? It's a post about the same error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you might be having a version of numpy that is incompatible with the version  used by the tensorflow object detection API. To solve this issue you can upgrade numpy to the latest version with the below command.

```
pip install -U numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

Then,

```
pip install numpy
```

For specific version of numpy,

```
pip install numpy==1.8
```