# Spyder imports numpy from the wrong python environment

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, spyder, nvidia-jetson

I want to import opencv in spyder using the IPython console. However, when I try to do this, I get an import error on numpy.

Platform: Jetson xavier
Spyder version: 3.2.6
I'm using 'virtualenv' to manage my virtual environment.

What works:
I can import cv2 in python using a bash terminal. Steps to reproduce:

1. Activate my virtual environment by running `source my_env/bin/activate`
2. Start python by running `python`
3. Import opencv by running `import cv2`
4. Success

I use spyder as my IDE and I want to import opencv in a python script run by spyder. However, when I run `import cv2` I get `ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`. Steps to reproduce:

1. In spyder in `preferences` set the `Python interpreter` to the one from my virtual environment (`~/my_env/bin/python3`)
2. Restart IPython console
3. Type `import cv2` in the IPython console
4. I get the `ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`

I already tried updating numpy, as recommended by [ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import) but this did not work.

**Update**
In spyder I can import numpy manually, and using `inspect.getfile(numpy)` tells me that spyder imported numpy from `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py`, While it sohuld import numpy from `~/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy`. Why is spyder importing numpy from the wrong environment?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder 3.2.6 is more than three years old. Please install our latest version (5.2.1) and try again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, tnx for your effort. Installing Spyder 5 did not work our for me. The Jetson is a has an aarch64 architecture, which is not supported by anaconda. Therefore the official Spyder5 package cannot be directly installed on the Jetson. Installing Spyder  using pip also does not work out. However, Spyder 3 can be easily installed using apt-get. Do you know if there is a procedure to install Spyder5 on an aarch64 system?