# pip uninstall does not remove package fully

Tags: python, numpy, pip

Long story short, numpy gave me error when I was importing matplotlib, so I wanted to `pip uninstall numpy` and reinstall it. but failed to fully uninstall numpy.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_26902/2971697587.py in <module>
----> 1 import matplotlib

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>
    105 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    106 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 107 from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
    108 from matplotlib.cbook import MatplotlibDeprecationWarning, sanitize_sequence
    109 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation  # deprecated

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py in <module>
     24 from matplotlib import _api, animation, cbook
     25 from matplotlib.cbook import ls_mapper
---> 26 from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
     27 from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
     28 from matplotlib._enums import JoinStyle, CapStyle

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in <module>
     80 import matplotlib as mpl
     81 import numpy as np
---> 82 from matplotlib import _api, cbook, scale
     83 from ._color_data import BASE_COLORS, TABLEAU_COLORS, CSS4_COLORS, XKCD_COLORS
     84 

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/scale.py in <module>
     16 import matplotlib as mpl
     17 from matplotlib import _api, docstring
---> 18 from matplotlib.ticker import (
     19     NullFormatter, ScalarFormatter, LogFormatterSciNotation, LogitFormatter,
     20     NullLocator, LogLocator, AutoLocator, AutoMinorLocator,

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py in <module>
    177 import matplotlib as mpl
    178 from matplotlib import _api, cbook
--> 179 from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
    180 
    181 _log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py in <module>
     44 
     45 from matplotlib import _api
---> 46 from matplotlib._path import (
     47     affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox, update_path_extents)
     48 from .path import Path

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I decided to uninstall and reinstall after the solutions found online doesn't work.
([ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import))

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip uninstall numpy
Uninstalling numpy-1.16.6:
  Would remove:
    /home/pi/.local/bin/f2py
    /home/pi/.local/bin/f2py2
    /home/pi/.local/bin/f2py2.7
    /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.16.6.dist-info/*
    /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.16.6
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install numpy
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.16.2)
```

supposing the first command already uninstalled numpy, why was requirement already satisfied?
I tried both `pip uninstall` and `pip3 uninstall`. then also went into `python` and `python3` to import the module as double check to see if the module is still installed. and the module was imported successfully.
also in the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` folder, `numpy` was still there.
what is the problem?
how can I successfully uninstall and reinstall numpy?

Edit: I manually went into the `dist-packages` directory of all versions of python, and `rm` all the numpy related files. then reinstallation works.

Comment: Could you mention which version of python you are using? Also, where are you running your programs on (i saw raspberry pi, but any software running the code?)

Comment: It appears you're mixing Python 2 and 3, as the error message clearly mentions numpy being installed for Python 2, even though you appear to want to install it for 3?

Comment: @AlirezaGhaffarian I did first python 2 then python3. ran both version of the uninstall/install commands, and checked both versions' folders. sorry for the confusion. I am running it on a raspberrypi4, it currently has no python code running in the background when I'm doing this.

Comment: @Grismar I ran the pip command for both python 2 and python 3. and tested/verified with both version. sorry for the confusion in the initial post.

Comment: "supposing the first command already uninstalled numpy, why was requirement already satisfied?" Notice how the version you uninstalled is `numpy-1.16.6`, but the one satisfying the requirement is `numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.16.2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the files with this commands

```
rm -rf f2py
rm -rf 2py2
rm -rf numpy-1.16.6.dist-info/*
rm -rf numpy/*
```

or only:

```
  rm  f2py
    rm  2py2
    rm  numpy-1.16.6.dist-info/*
    rm  numpy/*
```

Comment: so removing the file directly serves the same purpose? with no other drawbacks?

Comment: Yes you remove the files directly

Comment: You remove this , you need to care what you remove