# ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import GDAL

Tags: numpy, version, gdal

This question is already on StackOverflow ([ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import)) but no Answer helped.

I did install  GDAL: GDAL-3.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl and numpy: numpy-1.21.6+mkl-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl from the website : [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#_gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#_gdal)

By using the command `.ReadAsArray(0,0,500,500)`  I am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\adress\Codes\EdgeN2m.py", line 26, in <module>
    e = EDGE.ReadAsArray(0,0,500,500)

  File "C:\Users\name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 3655, in ReadAsArray
    from osgeo import gdal_array

  File "C:\Users\name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal_array.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _gdal_array

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Comment: You should be able to install everything into a `conda` environment and forget about `*.whl`. But you may have to hold back the `gdal` version, e.g. `conda create -n test_env python=3.9 gdal=3.1 numpy` .

Comment: Make sure you install numpy >= 1.21.x. Your version of numpy is 1.19.x (C_API_VERSION=0xd ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the numpy with different version to check which one can work.

For me, I install gdal-3.4.3 which is compatible with numpy-1.22.0

Hope this helps.