# ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import in Google Colab

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

i want to import some libraries below to load train model from checkpoint:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.utils import config_util
```

instead, i got some errors like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-47dd4b277c51> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
      4 from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
----> 5 from object_detection.builders import model_builder
      6 from object_detection.utils import config_util

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py in <module>
     21 from numpy.core import(
     22      intp, float32, empty, arange, array_repr, ndarray, isnat, array)
---> 23 import numpy.linalg.lapack_lite
     24 
     25 from io import StringIO

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Here's a list of installed libraries in my Google Colab environment

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- --------------------
absl-py                       1.4.0
alabaster                     0.7.13
albumentations                1.2.1
altair                        4.2.2
anyio                         3.6.2
apache-beam                   2.46.0
appdirs                       1.4.4
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
arviz                         0.15.1
astropy                       5.2.2
astunparse                    1.6.3
attrs                         23.1.0
audioread                     3.0.0
autograd                      1.5
avro-python3                  1.10.2
Babel                         2.12.1
backcall                      0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.11.2
bleach                        6.0.0
blis                          0.7.9
blosc2                        2.0.0
bokeh                         2.4.3
branca                        0.6.0
CacheControl                  0.12.11
cached-property               1.5.2
cachetools                    5.3.0
catalogue                     2.0.8
certifi                       2022.12.7
cffi                          1.15.1
chardet                       4.0.0
charset-normalizer            2.0.12
chex                          0.1.7
click                         8.1.3
cloudpickle                   2.2.1
cmake                         3.25.2
cmdstanpy                     1.1.0
colorama                      0.4.6
colorcet                      3.0.1
colorlover                    0.3.0
community                     1.0.0b1
confection                    0.0.4
cons                          0.4.5
contextlib2                   0.6.0.post1
contourpy                     1.0.7
convertdate                   2.4.0
crcmod                        1.7
cryptography                  40.0.2
cufflinks                     0.17.3
cupy-cuda11x                  11.0.0
cvxopt                        1.3.0
cvxpy                         1.3.1
cycler                        0.11.0
cymem                         2.0.7
Cython                        0.29.34
dask                          2022.12.1
datascience                   0.17.6
db-dtypes                     1.1.1
dbus-python                   1.2.16
debugpy                       1.6.6
decorator                     4.4.2
defusedxml                    0.7.1
dill                          0.3.1.1
distributed                   2022.12.1
dlib                          19.24.1
dm-tree                       0.1.8
docopt                        0.6.2
docutils                      0.16
dopamine-rl                   4.0.6
duckdb                        0.7.1
earthengine-api               0.1.350
easydict                      1.10
ecos                          2.0.12
editdistance                  0.6.2
en-core-web-sm                3.5.0
entrypoints                   0.4
ephem                         4.1.4
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
etils                         1.2.0
etuples                       0.3.8
exceptiongroup                1.1.1
fastai                        2.7.12
fastavro                      1.7.3
fastcore                      1.5.29
fastdownload                  0.0.7
fasteners                     0.18
fastjsonschema                2.16.3
fastprogress                  1.0.3
fastrlock                     0.8.1
filelock                      3.12.0
firebase-admin                5.3.0
Flask                         2.2.4
flatbuffers                   23.3.3
flax                          0.6.9
folium                        0.14.0
fonttools                     4.39.3
frozendict                    2.3.7
fsspec                        2023.4.0
future                        0.18.3
gast                          0.4.0
GDAL                          3.3.2
gdown                         4.6.6
gensim                        4.3.1
geographiclib                 2.0
geopy                         2.3.0
gin-config                    0.5.0
glob2                         0.7
google                        2.0.3
google-api-core               2.11.0
google-api-python-client      2.84.0
google-auth                   2.17.3
google-auth-httplib2          0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib          1.0.0
google-cloud-bigquery         3.9.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage 2.19.1
google-cloud-core             2.3.2
google-cloud-datastore        2.15.1
google-cloud-firestore        2.11.0
google-cloud-language         2.9.1
google-cloud-storage          2.8.0
google-cloud-translate        3.11.1
google-colab                  1.0.0
google-crc32c                 1.5.0
google-pasta                  0.2.0
google-resumable-media        2.5.0
googleapis-common-protos      1.59.0
googledrivedownloader         0.4
graphviz                      0.20.1
greenlet                      2.0.2
grpcio                        1.54.0
grpcio-status                 1.48.2
gspread                       3.4.2
gspread-dataframe             3.0.8
gym                           0.25.2
gym-notices                   0.0.8
h5netcdf                      1.1.0
h5py                          3.8.0
hdfs                          2.7.0
hijri-converter               2.3.1
holidays                      0.23
holoviews                     1.15.4
html5lib                      1.1
httpimport                    1.3.0
httplib2                      0.21.0
humanize                      4.6.0
hyperopt                      0.2.7
idna                          3.4
imageio                       2.25.1
imageio-ffmpeg                0.4.8
imagesize                     1.4.1
imbalanced-learn              0.10.1
imgaug                        0.4.0
immutabledict                 2.2.4
importlib-resources           5.12.0
imutils                       0.5.4
inflect                       6.0.4
iniconfig                     2.0.0
intel-openmp                  2023.1.0
ipykernel                     5.5.6
ipython                       7.34.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipython-sql                   0.4.1
ipywidgets                    7.7.1
itsdangerous                  2.1.2
jax                           0.4.8
jaxlib                        0.4.7+cuda11.cudnn86
jieba                         0.42.1
Jinja2                        3.1.2
joblib                        1.2.0
jsonpickle                    3.0.1
jsonschema                    4.3.3
jupyter-client                6.1.12
jupyter-console               6.1.0
jupyter_core                  5.3.0
jupyter-server                1.24.0
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets            3.0.7
kaggle                        1.5.13
keras                         2.12.0
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
korean-lunar-calendar         0.3.1
langcodes                     3.3.0
lazy_loader                   0.2
libclang                      16.0.0
librosa                       0.10.0.post2
lightgbm                      3.3.5
lit                           16.0.2
llvmlite                      0.39.1
locket                        1.0.0
logical-unification           0.4.5
LunarCalendar                 0.0.9
lvis                          0.5.3
lxml                          4.9.2
Markdown                      3.4.3
markdown-it-py                2.2.0
MarkupSafe                    2.1.2
matplotlib                    3.7.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
matplotlib-venn               0.11.9
mdurl                         0.1.2
miniKanren                    1.0.3
missingno                     0.5.2
mistune                       0.8.4
mizani                        0.8.1
mkl                           2019.0
ml-dtypes                     0.1.0
mlxtend                       0.14.0
more-itertools                9.1.0
moviepy                       1.0.3
mpmath                        1.3.0
msgpack                       1.0.5
multipledispatch              0.6.0
multitasking                  0.0.11
murmurhash                    1.0.9
music21                       8.1.0
natsort                       8.3.1
nbclient                      0.7.4
nbconvert                     6.5.4
nbformat                      5.8.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
networkx                      3.1
nibabel                       3.0.2
nltk                          3.8.1
notebook                      6.4.8
numba                         0.56.4
numexpr                       2.8.4
numpy                         1.23.5
oauth2client                  4.1.3
oauthlib                      3.2.2
object-detection              0.1
objsize                       0.6.1
opencv-contrib-python         4.7.0.72
opencv-python                 4.7.0.72
opencv-python-headless        4.7.0.72
openpyxl                      3.0.10
opt-einsum                    3.3.0
optax                         0.1.5
orbax-checkpoint              0.2.1
orjson                        3.8.11
osqp                          0.6.2.post8
packaging                     23.1
palettable                    3.3.3
pandas                        1.5.3
pandas-datareader             0.10.0
pandas-gbq                    0.17.9
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
panel                         0.14.4
param                         1.13.0
parso                         0.8.3
partd                         1.4.0
pathlib                       1.0.1
pathy                         0.10.1
patsy                         0.5.3
pep517                        0.13.0
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        8.4.0
pip                           23.0.1
pip-tools                     6.6.2
platformdirs                  3.3.0
plotly                        5.13.1
plotnine                      0.10.1
pluggy                        1.0.0
polars                        0.17.3
pooch                         1.6.0
portalocker                   2.7.0
portpicker                    1.3.9
prefetch-generator            1.0.3
preshed                       3.0.8
prettytable                   0.7.2
proglog                       0.1.10
progressbar2                  4.2.0
prometheus-client             0.16.0
promise                       2.3
prompt-toolkit                3.0.38
prophet                       1.1.2
proto-plus                    1.22.2
protobuf                      3.20.3
psutil                        5.9.5
psycopg2                      2.9.6
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
py-cpuinfo                    9.0.0
py4j                          0.10.9.7
pyarrow                       9.0.0
pyasn1                        0.5.0
pyasn1-modules                0.3.0
pycocotools                   2.0.6
pycparser                     2.21
pyct                          0.5.0
pydantic                      1.10.7
pydata-google-auth            1.7.0
pydot                         1.4.2
pydot-ng                      2.0.0
pydotplus                     2.0.2
PyDrive                       1.3.1
pyerfa                        2.0.0.3
pygame                        2.3.0
Pygments                      2.14.0
PyGObject                     3.36.0
pymc                          5.1.2
PyMeeus                       0.5.12
pymongo                       3.13.0
pymystem3                     0.2.0
PyOpenGL                      3.1.6
pyparsing                     2.4.7
pyrsistent                    0.19.3
PySocks                       1.7.1
pytensor                      2.10.1
pytest                        7.2.2
python-apt                    0.0.0
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-louvain                0.16
python-slugify                8.0.1
python-utils                  3.5.2
pytz                          2022.7.1
pytz-deprecation-shim         0.1.0.post0
pyviz-comms                   2.2.1
PyWavelets                    1.4.1
PyYAML                        5.4.1
pyzmq                         23.2.1
qdldl                         0.1.7
qudida                        0.0.4
regex                         2022.10.31
requests                      2.27.1
requests-oauthlib             1.3.1
requests-unixsocket           0.2.0
rich                          13.3.4
rpy2                          3.5.5
rsa                           4.9
sacrebleu                     2.2.0
scikit-image                  0.19.3
scikit-learn                  1.2.2
scipy                         1.10.1
scs                           3.2.3
seaborn                       0.12.2
Send2Trash                    1.8.0
sentencepiece                 0.1.99
seqeval                       1.2.2
setuptools                    67.7.2
shapely                       2.0.1
six                           1.16.0
sklearn-pandas                2.2.0
smart-open                    6.3.0
sniffio                       1.3.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soundfile                     0.12.1
soupsieve                     2.4.1
soxr                          0.3.5
spacy                         3.5.2
spacy-legacy                  3.0.12
spacy-loggers                 1.0.4
Sphinx                        3.5.4
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
SQLAlchemy                    2.0.10
sqlparse                      0.4.4
srsly                         2.4.6
statsmodels                   0.13.5
sympy                         1.11.1
tables                        3.8.0
tabulate                      0.8.10
tblib                         1.7.0
tenacity                      8.2.2
tensorboard                   2.12.2
tensorboard-data-server       0.7.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.12.0
tensorflow-addons             0.20.0
tensorflow-datasets           4.8.3
tensorflow-estimator          2.12.0
tensorflow-gcs-config         2.12.0
tensorflow-hub                0.13.0
tensorflow-io                 0.32.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.32.0
tensorflow-metadata           1.13.1
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.7.4
tensorflow-probability        0.19.0
tensorflow-text               2.12.1
tensorstore                   0.1.36
termcolor                     2.3.0
terminado                     0.17.1
text-unidecode                1.3
textblob                      0.17.1
tf-models-official            2.12.0
tf-slim                       1.1.0
thinc                         8.1.9
threadpoolctl                 3.1.0
tifffile                      2023.4.12
tinycss2                      1.2.1
toml                          0.10.2
tomli                         2.0.1
toolz                         0.12.0
torch                         2.0.0+cu118
torchaudio                    2.0.1+cu118
torchdata                     0.6.0
torchsummary                  1.5.1
torchtext                     0.15.1
torchvision                   0.15.1+cu118
tornado                       6.2
tqdm                          4.65.0
traitlets                     5.7.1
triton                        2.0.0
tweepy                        4.13.0
typeguard                     2.13.3
typer                         0.7.0
typing_extensions             4.5.0
tzdata                        2023.3
tzlocal                       4.3
uritemplate                   4.1.1
urllib3                       1.26.15
vega-datasets                 0.9.0
wasabi                        1.1.1
wcwidth                       0.2.6
webcolors                     1.13
webencodings                  0.5.1
websocket-client              1.5.1
Werkzeug                      2.3.0
wheel                         0.40.0
widgetsnbextension            3.6.4
wordcloud                     1.8.2.2
wrapt                         1.14.1
xarray                        2022.12.0
xarray-einstats               0.5.1
xgboost                       1.7.5
xlrd                          2.0.1
yellowbrick                   1.5
yfinance                      0.2.18
zict                          3.0.0
zipp                          3.15.0
zstandard                     0.21.0
```

Previously i used same libraries to train and it work fine AND two weeks ago i got no error in this part. I have upgrade and downgrade the numpy version based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import) , but it still shows same errors. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Hy, I just figure out to solve the error.

When i check the list of libraries that been installed, it shows that the numpy version was **1.23.5**. Instead, when i check the numpy version using

```
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

it shows that the numpy version was **1.22.4**

So i tried to uninstall the numpy library using

```
!pip uninstall numpy
```

and re-install the numpy again with the version that show in the list, like below

```
!pip install numpy==1.23.5
```

After restart runtime, I run the code to import the libraries and it works.
I hope this methods can help anyone who got the same error